# How to determine which ListView item was clicked upon by the user?

Tags: android-listview

how to fill listview with data that comes from online database.
Also,say the list view has several rows of items(say a list containing book titles),and the user clicks one of them.
How can the app determine which row was selected by the user,so that the details of the item(book) will be then fethed from the database and displayed in another activity.

So basically what I am asking is-How to determine which item on the listview was selested by the user.

Comment: You need to follow a **very basic** ListView tutorial, then. A quick Google search is your best friend.

Comment: appreciate that...thanks for answering

Comment: Lars Vogel has a beautiful generic tutorial on ListViews (Just to name a famous one). But searching around you can find many specific tutorials, covering nearly all the aspects of ListViews and ExpandableListViews.